Creating SSL Encryption with Let's Encrypt and DDNS
I have a home server running nginx and i wanted to add a TLS/SSL Encryption to my domain i bought.
Also a DDNS provider updates a wildcard domain to my public IP dynamically.
There is a Frame-Forwarding on my domain, which points to the wildcard, which points to my server.
Now my problem lies within creating the certification / the challenges within the certification.
The domain does not point to my server, it only forwards it. Thus it randomly selects an IP from the domain provider with some message "Buy Webhosting" blah blah blah.
If i directly point the domain to my home server the certification works and gets generated correctly. But to renew it, i would have to manually edit the IP every 24 hours, because the domain provider doesn't have a DDNS service.
Does someone have an idea how to fix the issue?

...But to renew it, i would have to manually edit the IP every 24 hours... I don't understand why?

My ISP changes my public IP very often.

That's why you use DNS. As long as your domain name stays the same and your certificate has that domain name as one of its subject alternative names (SANs), your IP address doesn't matter and can change every second.
